# How to efficiently join an arbitrary number of RDDs?

Tags: java, join, apache-spark, java-8

Joining two RDDs is simple with a `RDD1.join(RDD2)`. However, if I keep an arbitrary number of RDDs in a `List<JavaRDD>`, how can I efficiently join them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please note that you cannot join [`JavaRDD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html). You would need to obtain a [`JavaPairRDD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html) by using:

- `groupBy()` (or `keyBy()`)
- `cartesian()`
- `[flat]mapToPair()`
- `zipWithIndex()` (useful because it adds index where there is none)
- etc.

Then, once you have your list, you can join them all like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> linesA = sc.parallelizePairs(Arrays.asList(
                                            new Tuple2<>(1, "a1"),
                                            new Tuple2<>(2, "a2"),
                                            new Tuple2<>(3, "a3"),
                                            new Tuple2<>(4, "a4")));
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> linesB = sc.parallelizePairs(Arrays.asList(
                                            new Tuple2<>(1, "b1"),
                                            new Tuple2<>(5, "b5"),
                                            new Tuple2<>(3, "b3")));
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> linesC = sc.parallelizePairs(Arrays.asList(
                                            new Tuple2<>(1, "c1"),
                                            new Tuple2<>(5, "c6"),
                                            new Tuple2<>(6, "c3")));

// the list of RDDs
List<JavaPairRDD<Integer, String>> allLines = Arrays.asList(linesA, linesB, linesC);

// since we probably don't want to modify any of the datasets in the list, we will
// copy the first one in a separate variable to keep the result
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> res = allLines.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < allLines.size(); ++i) {  // note we skip position 0 !
    res = res.join(allLines.get(i))
    /*[1]*/  .mapValues(tuple -> tuple._1 + ':' + tuple._2);
}
```

The line with `[1]` is the important one, because it maps a

`JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<String,String>>` back into a

`JavaPairRdd<Integer,String>` which makes it compatible with further joins.

Based on chrisw answer, this could be put into "one line" like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> res;
res = allLines.stream()
              .reduce((rdd1, rdd2) -> rdd1.join(rdd2).mapValues(tup -> tup._1 + ':' + tup._2))
              .get();  // get value from Optional<JavaPairRDD>
```

Finally, some thoughts on performance. In the above example, I used string concatenation to reduce the result of the join back to an RDD of the same type. If you have a lot of RDDs, you could probably speed this up a bit by using the `for loop` version with `JavaPairRDD<Integer, StringBuilder> res`, where you do the first join by hand. I will post more details if required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the JavaRDD class/interface but perhaps you could solve this problem using the higher-order function `reduce` in Java 8, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

```
final List<JavaRDD> list = getList(); // where getList is your list implementation containing JavaRDD instances

// The JavaRDD class provides rdd() to get the RDD
final JavaRDD rdd = list.stream().map(JavaRDD::rdd).reduce(RDD::join);
```

An example with the String class would be something like: -

```
Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz").reduce(String::concat);
```

Which produces

> foobarbaz

Comment: I think I undertand the idea but JavaRDD:: yields no join.

Comment: I've just taken a look at the javadoc, if the `rdd()` method returns the RDD, then you can use the map higher order function, see the ammendment